Kotlin Flow does not work as expected if the user does not use the app
I have a food delivery KMM app, and for fetching the restaurants lists, I am not sure if I should use Flow or suspend methods.
I use KMM with Firestore, and my biggest concern is having the data up to date when the user opens the app.
The bigest problem that I see with Flow is the fact that if a simple user opens the app after 1-2 months, the Flow together with sync will take some time to update all the data from the remote db.
In the other hand I believe that if I would switch to suspend, the user will get the latest data from the single call suspend to the remote db.
Is the issue of data sync related to Flow? Why this happens?

If it takes a Flow some time to update the data, why would you expect a suspend function to be faster?  This has nothing to do with flow versus suspend, and everything to do with how and when you're loading the up-to-date data whichever way you're doing it.

Wouldn't the sync of data will take more with flow?

No, why?  It sounds like you think flows work completely differently from suspend functions.  They don't.

The main difference is that flows remain active and continuously wait for updates, whereas suspend functions complete their execution as soon as the call is finished. Is that correct?

Some flows do that, but it's perfectly possible for flows to finish and complete promptly.

what type of flows are you referring to?

kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow ?
